# Pandas to_gbq method DataFrame schema doesn't match to the table

Tags: python, pandas, automation, google-bigquery, data-warehouse

We're working on an app and were collecting stats from it. Initially we were dumping stats on googl sheets so we downloaded it as csv and uploaded the data to bigquery. We succesfully uploaded data with the schema we wanted.

When we are re-running the app and added a step to upload it to the test table which contains the initial data, gbq tells us the following error:

> Please verify that the structure and data types in the DataFrame match
>   the schema of the destination table.

I tried comparing the table with the data being uploaded.

```
a.dtypes (bigquery table)
Out[16]: 
start_timestamp    datetime64[ns]
name               object
url                object
email              object
destination        object
database           object
update_timestamp   datetime64[ns]
query_info         object
query_runtime      float64
error_log          object
dtype: object


upload_df.dtypes (df being uploaded)
Out[17]: 
start_timestamp    datetime64[ns]
name               object
url                object
email              object
destination        object
database           object
update_timestamp   datetime64[ns]
query_info         object
query_runtime      float64
error_log          object
dtype: object
```

It's weird that they have the same schema but pandas gbq is giving an error.

Any help or direction to resolve this issue is appreciated!

Comment: Can you add to the post the actual schema from BigQuery? But not the one that you get when the data is already in a pandas dataframe.